# How does C handle mixed precision operation

Tags: c, type-conversion, double, implicit-conversion

```
float  FLOAT  = 1.0f;
double DOUBLE = 2.0;

float  a = FLOAT / DOUBLE;
double b = FLOAT / DOUBLE;
```

Are `a` and `b` calculated in the same way?

How are `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` converted in compile?

It seems the default conversion is up-conversion to prevent loss.

Actually I'm doing some calculation on GPU which is precision sensitive and the code should look like this:

```
float a = FLOAT / 2.0 + 1.0/3.0;
```

where the code contains very long expression with many numbers and vars (actually generated from Matlab code).

Then how do I control such conversion behavior? 
Except writing all the numbers in like `2.0f` (thousands of numbers in expressions).

Comment: That should be covered by [usual arithmetic conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Comment: You can have a look at expressions implicit type conversion in c, which helps in clearing your doubts

Comment: See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules), scroll down to "the usual arithmetic conversions". (It isn't an exact duplicate of this question, since it mostly speaks of integers.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is double.

So in the both initializing expressions of the declarations

```
float  a = FLOAT / DOUBLE;
double b = FLOAT / DOUBLE;
```

the operand of the type `float` is converted to the type `double`. Thus the result of the expressions has the type `double`. In the first declaration the result further is converted to `float` because the variable `a` has the type `float`.

Comment: thanks. so it means I will suffer from the implicit conversion in the SP computation if the numbers are not written in like `2.0f`. Is there another way to control the implicit conversion?

Comment: @CHCl3 To control an implicit conversion you should use an explicit conversion.:)

Comment: @CHCl3 The only thing you can do is to cast all operands that aren't float to the intended type. `float  a = FLOAT / (float)DOUBLE;`. As you may notice now, using or not `f` for literals can be very important.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow As I mentioned above the expression is very long and such method is not cheap (I have to replace all the numbers to desired precision, maybe thousands of numbers). Is there a way to change the default conversion behavior?

Comment: @CHCl3 Use a loop and an array of values.

Comment: @CHCl3 — there certainly isn’t a standard way to change the rules.  You might find an option in your compiler’ manual, but there’s nothing in the question to identify the compiler you’re using.